# Proving a function is differentiable at 1 point, but discontinuous everywhere else

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable only at $x = 7$ and continuous nowhere else. Verify both properties.

Let $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
14x-49,  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
x^2, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$$

Let $x_n = 7 - \frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n = 7 - \frac{\sqrt 2}{n}$.
So, 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n) - f(7)}{x_n - 7} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{14(7-\frac{1}{n}) - 49}{7-\frac{1}{n}-7} = 14$$
Similarly, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(y_n) - f(7)}{y_n - 7} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{14(7-\frac{\sqrt 2}{n}) - 49}{7-\frac{\sqrt 2}{n}-7} = 14$$ So, the limit at $x=7$ exists, therefore $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at $x=7$.

Now to prove that the function is continuous nowhere else, let c be a rational number (a limit point of the set of irrationals) and let $x_n = c - \frac{\sqrt 2}{n}$. Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c.         $
Then, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = (c-\frac{\sqrt 2}{n})^2 = c^2         $$
But, $f(c) = 14(c) - 49$. These two are only equal when $c = 7$. Thus by the sequential criterion of discontinuity, $f(x)$ is discontinuous everywhere else.

Have I done this proof correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. you have proved that if $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $c$ is rational then $c=7$. You also have to show that if $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $c$ is irrational then $c=7$ (but the proof is similar to the case of rational $c$).

Comment: Would I have to construct a sequence of rationals that approach an irrational to work the other case?

Comment: @carbonv2 Yes, that is what you have to do.

Comment: Would the sequence $x_n = \frac{\lfloor nc \rfloor}{n}$ work?

Comment: @carbonv2 Yes, that will work. But for the proof you are not required to produce such a  sequence explicitly. You can simply use the fact that rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ahh, so something along the lines of let y be an irrational number. The density of rational numbers allows us to construct a sequence of rational numbers converging to y. The limit of this f(x_n) is 14*(x_n) - 49, but f(y) is y^2. Thus f is not cont. except at 7.

Comment: @carbonv2 Exactly. You will again get the same equation $14 y-49=y^{2}$ or $(y-7)^{2}=0$.